# Regular expression : extract text from middle of line

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the text from below sample as follows - 
Sample text -

```
Link speed type is OK, link duplex type is DOWN
Unknown-speed mode, Link speed type is OK, Flow-control is disabled
Link speed type is OK, link duplex type is DOWN, Flow-control is disabled
```

From this i want to extract the line starting with Link speed(It can be on start of line or in middle line) upto the Flow-Control...(this part can or cannot be present).

So the desired output would be like this -

```
Link speed type is OK, link duplex type is DOWN
Link speed type is OK
Link speed type is OK, link duplex type is DOWN
```

means first and third line full and from second line only link speed part excluding comma and Flow-control part.. 
I tried few ways..

```
^\s*(?:.*,)?\s*(Link speed.*)
```

Problem - this selects 2nd line till the end.

```
^\s*(?:.*,)?\s*(Link speed.*(?=\W*Flow-control))
```

It does  not select the first line which does not have flow-control in it.

Comment: have you considered using String.contains() + while loop?

Comment: @nafas no..actually i need to use this via regular expression. I need to add this expression in already existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use non-greedy modifier `?`:

```
(Link speed.*?)(Flow-control|$)
```

This will match anything starting from `'Link speed'` and to `'Flow-control'` or end of line.

Comment: Thanks Suor. It worked as per expected. Could you please add more details about non-greedy modifier `?` I mean about the working of this. I was trying this but was getting text upto speed keyword only(might be using it inappropriately)

Comment: By default all modifiers like `*` or `+` are greedy, meaning they capture as much as they can and then backtrack to satisfy anything following them. Non-greedy versions like `*?` and `+?` will match the least times possible first (0 and 1) and then capture more only to satisfy following parts of regex. So if you end regex with `.*?` it will match empty string. Here is an example - http://www.channelping.com/practicalperl/?id=lectures/regex/greedy_vs_nongreedy.

Comment: This matches `flow-control` also.

Comment: It matches `Flow-control` as separate capture. Just use the first one.

Comment: Thanks AvinashRaj and Suor . It cleared my confusion. I was wondering why it was selecting only one char..

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
\bLink speed\b.*?(?=\bFlow-control\b|$)
```

`.*?` will match upto the string `Flow-control` if it present or otherwise this would match all the chars upto the line end.

**OR**

To get the output you expected without comma,

```
\bLink speed\b.*?(?=,\s*\bFlow-control\b|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hF0yA0/1)

In java, you need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to extract a particular substring.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)\\bLink speed\\b.*?(?=,\\s*\\bFlow-control\\b|$)");
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash. As per my understanding positive lookahead is to check if the given text is present next. It wont capture the text. Am I right? 
Could you put more light on positive lookahead?

Comment: @KuldeepSidhu yep, you're right. It's just an assertion and it won't match any characters. Simple google search on positive lookahead will help you to know more.